# Who is the receiver in a nft_transfer_call?

Tags: nearprotocol

I have an `NFT` contract and a `Market` deployed for it.
I've not been using `nft_transfer_call` for accepting a bid but adding it in now.
In the case an `NFT`/`Media` owner accepting a bid the current implemented flow is:

1. Call `[nft-contract].accept_bid(token_id, bidder)` which starts a cross contract call
2. `[market-contract].xcc_market_accept_bid(token_id, bidder, design.creator, design.owner_id, design.prev_owner)`
3. Market takes care of paying out shares, removing bid and calls back `NFT`
4. `[nft-contract].xcc_media_nft_transfer(token_id, receiver_id)`
5. Transfer moves `NFT`/`Media` to new owner and finale!

---

I understand this is not the correct way as I should use `nft_transfer_call` and based on the Standars this is how the above calls are supposed to be as I understood:

```
[nft-contract].nft_transfer_call({
  "receiver_id": ${market_address}, ? or ${bidder}
  "token_id": ${token_id},
  "msg": "${token_id} ${bidder} ${creator} ${owner_id} ${prev_owner}"
})
```

which should transfer token internally and then fires:

```
[market-contract].nft_on_transfer({
  "sender_id": ${sender_of_nft_transfer_call},
  "previous_owner_id": ${get_media_prev_owner_from_store},
  "token_id": ${token_id_passed_by_front_end},
  "msg": "${token_id} ${bidder} ${creator} ${owner_id} ${prev_owner}", // parameters for Market contract
})
```

that distributes payouts, updates new shares, and finally calls back:

```
[nft-contract].nft_resolve_transfer({
  "sender_id": ${sender_of_nft_transfer_call},
  "receiver_id":  ${market_address}, ? or ${bidder},
  "token_id": ${token_id},
})
```

The question is who is the `receiver_id` in this case (the market or the new owner)? I understand approval management Standard might be better solution here but I'm trying to keep it simple and solve it with the transfer call.

---

- [Market interface](https://docs.ysn.design/contracts/market)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your code correctly, the `bidder` is the value for `receiver_id` in both functions. From the [docs][1]:

```
// * `receiver_id`: the valid NEAR account receiving the token
```

```
// Arguments:
// * `receiver_id`: the valid NEAR account receiving the token.
// * `token_id`: the token to send.
// * `approval_id`: expected approval ID. A number smaller than
//    2^53, and therefore representable as JSON. See Approval Management
//    standard for full explanation.
// * `memo` (optional): for use cases that may benefit from indexing or
//    providing information for a transfer.
// * `msg`: specifies information needed by the receiving contract in
//    order to properly handle the transfer. Can indicate both a function to
//    call and the parameters to pass to that function.
function nft_transfer_call(
  receiver_id: string,
  token_id: string,
  approval_id: number|null,
  memo: string|null,
  msg: string,
): Promise {}
```

Should match argument in `nft_resolve_transfer()`

```
// * `receiver_id`: the `receiver_id` argument given to `nft_transfer_call`
```

```
    // Arguments:
// * `sender_id`: the sender of `ft_transfer_call`
// * `receiver_id`: the `receiver_id` argument given to `nft_transfer_call`
// * `token_id`: the `token_id` argument given to `ft_transfer_call`
// * `approved_token_ids`: if using Approval Management, contract MUST provide
//   set of original approved accounts in this argument, and restore these
//   approved accounts in case of revert.
//
// Returns true if token was successfully transferred to `receiver_id`.
function nft_resolve_transfer(
  owner_id: string,
  receiver_id: string,
  token_id: string,
  approved_account_ids: null|string[],
): boolean {}


  [1]: https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core.html
```

Comment: This is correct. I have noticed it's not easy to read code in these comments so I'll expand in a separate answer. For folks who may find this, note that BenTheHumanMan is referencing the Nomicon spec documentation here: https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/Core.html#nft-interface

Answer (score 2):

As BenTheHumanMan said, the `receiver_id` will be the same.

Here is a snippet from the Rust example:

```rust
fn nft_transfer_call(
    &mut self,
    receiver_id: AccountId,
    token_id: TokenId,
    approval_id: Option<u64>,
    memo: Option<String>,
    msg: String,
) -> PromiseOrValue<bool> {
    assert_one_yocto();
    let sender_id = env::predecessor_account_id();
    let (old_owner, old_approvals) =
        self.internal_transfer(&sender_id, &receiver_id, &token_id, approval_id, memo);
    // Initiating receiver's call and the callback
    ext_receiver::nft_on_transfer(
        sender_id.clone(),
        old_owner.clone(),
        token_id.clone(),
        msg,
        &receiver_id,
        NO_DEPOSIT,
        env::prepaid_gas() - GAS_FOR_FT_TRANSFER_CALL,
    )
    .then(ext_self::nft_resolve_transfer(
        old_owner,
        receiver_id,
        token_id,
        old_approvals,
        &env::current_account_id(),
        NO_DEPOSIT,
        GAS_FOR_RESOLVE_TRANSFER,
    ))
    .into()
}
```

Note that we're using the `receiver_id` that's given to function initially and passing it to the callback (`nft_resolve_transfer`) after.

But perhaps to more directly answer your question… In the case where you're having folks bid on an NFT, using the transfer-and-call functionality might not be necessary. Without knowing much details about how bids work, I think you're right that approvals are a better fit.

There is an example [in Nomicon](https://nomicon.io/Standards/FungibleToken/Core.html) that may help. Note that this links to fungible tokens instead of non-fungible tokens, as I believe this is easier to understand. The linked page goes over a scenario where:

> Alice needs to issue 1 transaction, as opposed to 2 with a typical escrow workflow.

In short… pretend I want to pay 5 fungible tokens for a service, let's say an oracle. I pay 5 fungible tokens to an oracle contract, and in return they'll store my request, which presumably gets picked up and answered by off-chain services.

In order to:

1. Send my request for an off-chain service
2. Send fungible tokens

the typical workflow using an approvals system would be:

1. I allow the oracle to take 5 fungible tokens from me.
2. I sent a request, the oracle *tries to* take those 5 fungible tokens from me.
3. If successful, the request is stored, if unsuccessful, it says, "you need to allow me to take 5 tokens from you"

This isn't great and takes multiple transactions. In this scenario I could use the transfer-and-call functionality to simplify this. It would essentially say, "hey Fungible Token Contract, transfer 5 tokens to the oracle and then send them from extra information I've given in the `msg` parameter." (Perhaps the `msg` contains info like what type of request I have, the request details, how long before I no longer need an off-chain response, etc.)

---

Pulling back out of the fungible token example, this same thing applies to non-fungible tokens. The use case for transfer-and-call is a little less straightforward and may not suit all needs.

Please see the [NFT Approval Management standard spec](https://nomicon.io/Standards/NonFungibleToken/ApprovalManagement.html) for more details on that approach, which might be what you want for an auction.